# How to split a number into individual digits in CMD/Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd, delimiter

I want to split numbers into its individual digits and store them into variables using cmd/batch on Windows. For example, the number '38' should be stored as '3' in VAR1 and '8' in VAR2.

This is my current take on the issue:

```
@echo off
SET NUMBER=38
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 delims=0123456789" %%A IN ("%NUMBER%") DO (CALL :VARSET %%A %%B)
ECHO %NUMBER% has the fallowing digits:
ECHO 1st digit: %VAR1%
ECHO 2nd digit: %VAR2%
PAUSE
EXIT /B 0

:VARSET
set VAR1=%1
set VAR2=%2
GOTO:EOF
```

I want the output to be:

```
ECHO 38 has the fallowing digits:
ECHO 1st digit: 3
ECHO 2nd digit: 8
```

But I get:

```
ECHO 38 has the fallowing digits:
ECHO 1st digit: Echo is off.
ECHO 2nd digit: Echo is off.
```

The problem seem to be the fact that I use '0123456789' as my delimiter. Perhaps this is not doable at all using a FOR-LOOP?

Edit: Typos

Comment: You might find [SS64's page on substrings](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) of interest.

Comment: You seem to have understood [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) wrongly: `for /F` splits strings into tokens that are separated by *delimiters*, so they become removed; for example: `for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %I in ("_abc__def__gh") do @echo/%I,%J` will return `abc,def`; in your situation, the input string consists of delimiters only (all decimal digits, `delims=0123456789`), so there is nothing left to extract...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the hell of it:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "i=0"
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%A In ('"CMD/U/CEcho %*|Find /V """') Do (Set/A i+=1
    Set "Var[!i!]=%%A")
Set Var[
Timeout -1
```

Just run it as `file.cmd 5678` where `file.cmd` is the saved name of this script and `5678` an alphanumeric string to split into individual variables.

Answer (score 2):

Do it with simple math - and I suggest you start with the least significant digit to be able to easily reconstruct the value.

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
:Again
set "#=" & Set Place=0
Set /p "#=Enter # :"
if "%#%" equ "" goto :Eof
Set /A Test=#
:Loop
Set /A "Place+=1,#[!Place!]=Test %% 10,Test/=10"
If "%Test%" gtr "0" goto :Loop
Set #
Echo =====
For /f "delims==" %%A in ('Set #') Do set "%%A="
Goto :Again
```

Sample run:

```
Enter # :123456789
#=123456789
#[0]=9
#[1]=8
#[2]=7
#[3]=6
#[4]=5
#[5]=4
#[6]=3
#[7]=2
#[8]=1
=====
Enter # :
```

Answer (score 2):

Simpler and faster. Just put the maximum number of digits in the `for /L` command:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set NUMBER=%1
echo %NUMBER% has the following digits:

for /L %%i in (1,1,12) do if defined NUMBER (
   set "VAR[%%i]=!NUMBER:~0,1!"
   set "NUMBER=!NUMBER:~1!"
)

set VAR[
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Didn't see LotPings answer before I posted mine. Thank you for the answer, works aswell.

@Jeff Zeitlin for the link and aschipfl for the 'lesson' :)
A very simply solution is:

```
@echo off
SET NUMBER=38
SET VAR1=%NUMBER:~0,1%
SET VAR2=%NUMBER:~1,2%
ECHO %NUMBER% has the following digits:
ECHO 1st digit: %VAR1%
ECHO 2nd digit: %VAR2%
PAUSE
EXIT /B 0
```

Perhaps a more reusable approch would be:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET COUNT=0
SET NUMBER=1234567890
CALL :SPLITNUM %NUMBER%
PAUSE
EXIT /b 0

:SPLITNUM
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET NUMBER=%1
:LOOP
SET /A COUNT+=1
SET VAR%COUNT%=%NUMBER:~0,1%
ECHO VAR%COUNT% is !VAR%COUNT%!
SET NUMBER=%NUMBER:~1%
IF NOT "%NUMBER%"=="" (GOTO:LOOP)
ENDLOCAL
GOTO:EOF
```